# Run a directory of Junit tests in NetBeans 8.1

Tags: java, netbeans, junit, ant

I have a custom NetBeans project. My JUnit tests are organized in set of packages under a directory called src/junit. I have two ant targets in my build.xml file: one will run all of the tests and the other will run a single test. These are mapped to two actions in my project.xml file:

```
<action name="test">
    <target>test</target>
</action>
```

and

```
<action name="test.single">
    <script>build.xml</script>
    <target>test-single</target>
    <context>
        <property>test.class</property>
        <folder>src/junit</folder>
        <pattern>\.java$</pattern>
        <format>java-name</format>
        <arity>
            <one-file-only/>
        </arity>
    </context>
</action>
```

respectively. As a result, I can run all of the tests or any one of them through the NetBeans GUI.

I would like to add the capability to select a single directory of tests and run these. I cannot work out the right combination of action elements and ant targets to do this. Has anyone done this, and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Dump JUnit and just write a simple Java program that calls all the tests.  It will be easier and you won't have to reverse engineer how this XML file is supposed to get all the tests to be called.  You simply call the tests as regular method calls.  You can have a branch for just some of the tests, or all the tests, basically you would have the full power of a *real programming language* at your disposal.  Why do anything else?  There is no magic to testing.  Tests are code just like the program you are testing.